# disabling clickable property on items in listview

Tags: android, listview

I created one project in which there are 20 items in list view , out of them I want to disable 15 item unless they are purchased and as soon as they are purchased they become clickable , I tried this code:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(QuantitativeAptitude.this,
            R.layout.row, quantList){

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
             ListView lv = getListView();
                for (int i = 5; i <=20; i++){
                    View v = lv.getChildAt(i);
                    v.setEnabled(false);
                }
            return super.isEnabled(position);
        }

    });
```

but it wont help instead it crashes my application any suggestions.....

Answer (score 2):

I believe you may have to override the isEnabled method and in there you can specify a condition for if it's enabled or not. This method is called for each listviewitem in the collection, so for example:

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if(CONDITION_GOES_HERE){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

There are probably far better/easier ways of doing it, but this is the first thing that comes to mind.

Hopefully this will help you out :)

Comment: Thanx for your rply but as in my code i already used isEnabled method by using for loop, any other helpful answer ...

Comment: I understand that, but you're getting a list of all listviewitems inside of the isEnabled method, which you don't need. This method is called for every listviewitem that is created for its parent container. If you remove all of the code you have and simply use the code I've supplied I think you'll find it will work as you want it to. At least I believe that to be the case. There is no need for a loop as this is called on the individual items themselves.

Comment: can you show me an example of isEnabled (int position) method implementation, because i am not getting how to apply it for 15 items, and again converting them back to clickable state